# JSON and serializable Object

Tags: java, json, tcp

I want to send my custom object `Paper` with JSON over TCP.

Is it necessary that `Paper` have to implements `Serializable` although I am sending as JSON?

```
    JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject2.put("key", new Paper(250,333));

    client.sendJSON(jsonObject2);
```

Comment: `Serializable` is for serialization of objects to byte stream via standard Java facilities. I doubt that any JSON library will care about it (at least Jackson doesn't require it...)

Comment: Please refer to this link :
[Class to JsonObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330718/convert-class-into-a-jsonobject)